# How to figure out if I have registration on particular network in PJSIP?

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I have a VOIP IOS application based on pjsip. I have a problem with network switch. For example when my app becomes inactive the network might change and when I get push on incoming call I can not answer because I don't have registration. I don't know what is the best way to figure out if I have registration on PARTICULAR NETWORK or not. (It is not enough to check pjsua_acc_get_info because it still might have registration from previous network).

Answer (score 0):

Registration is done in a periodical basis. You can state that you are not registered if the time for registration has expired. So you should check also, as stated in [Chek account registration status](http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2008-October/005134.html) the field "expires" from the struct returned by pjsua_acc_get_info